# What direction to go with the [axis] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I rejected an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6180167) about working with an Axis-brand security camera. The editor wanted to add the [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis) tag, but the tag description says that it refers to "Apache Axis [, which] is a Web Services/SOAP/WSDL engine".

However, looking at the questions tagged with [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis), it appears that most of them are actually about displaying (or not displaying) axes in various graphing packages.

I would argue that there should not be a tag for the graphing concept, because all questions of that type should be tagged with other graphing-related tags.  At the same time, I don't think that it makes sense to leave the tag the way it is.

I propose that this tag should be renamed [apache-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis) (which is currently a synonym for [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis)) and that [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis) should be removed.

Comment: Agreed [tag:apache-axis] looks much clearer for me. If we really need a tag for coordinate system [tag:axis] is very arguable.

Comment: Apache naming scheme strikes, [again.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226637/213575) Oh, btw, "I would argue that there should not be a tag for the graphing concept" [tag:triangle] [tag:square] [tag:circle]....

Comment: @Braiam: Actually, triangles are pretty fundamental to 3D graphics, and there are lots of algorithms for operating on triangle lists.  So that tag is ok.  The others probably ought to die.

Comment: The tag wiki is misleading at the moment: As long as [apache-axis] is mapped to [axis] it's pretty useless telling people in the tag wiki that they shouldn't use [axis].

Comment: Agree with Tomalak. Tell people to stop using the [axis] tag when they have an actual possibility to use other. The current situation is (to state it in a educated manner) not very logical.

Answer (score 11):

After some consultation in [The trogdor chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45301970#45301970) I propose the following:

- break the synonym between [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis) and [apache-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis)
- reinstate the original wiki for Axis.
- retag [60 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baxis%5D+is%3Aq+%5Bapache%5D&mixed=0) to [apache-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis)
- revisit [15 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/978977) that once had the tag [apache-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis)
- let the community clean-up/retag [250 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baxis%5D+%22apache%22+is%3Aq&mixed=0) that seems to be about apache axis.
- let the community clean-up [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis) for question about coordinates and optical axis.

For sake of consistency I wonder if tag [axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis2) needs to be renamed to tag [apache-axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis2)

Answer (score 1):

I came across multiple tag-removals as well in review.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7181176

I would recommend removing the overlap by using [apache-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis) as the primary tag for the Apache Axis framework, but keep (redefine) [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis) for questions related to the mathematical of graphical coordinate lines, as this is a valid usage.

**Update**: I edited the tag wiki with advise to not use the [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis) for Apache Axis, and my edit was approved.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a great help because [apache-axis] is a synonym of [axis], so it can't be used.

Comment: I agree with JasenMArcher. Now there is effectively no tag for Apache Axis 1.x because the description of [axis] says that it shouldn't be used for Apache Axis, and [apache-axis] is an alias of [axis].

Comment: Would it not be better to remove / break the alias?

Comment: I have recently noticed this confusion in tags and help community to de-tag [axis] for Axis camera brand related questions. And I still see axis being an alias of apache-axis, so, I wonder, what needs to be done to break it, is there ongoing proposal for that to vote?