# How to rollback tag wiki edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, rollbacks

As a result of [What direction to go with the [axis] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276302/5277820) someone [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13474722/4) the tag info of [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis) to:

> Don't use the axis to refer to Apache Axis, use apache-axis instead. See
>
> What direction to go with the [axis] tag?

This tag info is very confusing, because:

1. it lacks information about Apache Axis (removed by the edit).
2. [apache-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis) is remapped to [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis), so the result is the same.

I have not enough reputation ([20.000](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)) to rollback the edit. I could copy [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13474722/3) into a new suggested edit, but I think that smells. I think, it would be better, someone with enough reputation does a rollback of the edit.

What should I do?