# Rollback the PostScript tag info page?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation, tag-wiki

I was curating the set of links to online references in the [PostScript tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postscript/info). When the Documentation project opened, I copied them there and placed a link in the info page. But I just noticed that Documentation is gone, and I don't see a rollback button or even a flag button.

Do I just copy/paste the source as a new edit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing documentation links from the tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357802/removing-documentation-links-from-the-tags)

Comment: Similar to this question (which doesn't have an answer): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338520/how-to-rollback-tag-wiki-edit.  It indicates that you need 20K reputation to rollback, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges isn't specific about whether tag info rollback applies, specifically.

Comment: The issue here isn't removing the docmentation links from the tag info page.  It's about restoring the links that were previously moved from the tag info page to the documentation, which is now unavailable.  The question is about rolling back the prior change on the tag info page to the older set of links that existed at that time, but there's no rollback link on the tag info page, like with most other content-based areas of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Making a new edit seems like the simplest course of action. The only annoyance is that my last best copy was in the Docs. So I have to dig it out of the archive. Wish me luck!