# What's the deal with [axis] and [apache-axis]?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

[axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis) tag description says:

> Don't use the [axis] tag to refer to Apache Axis. Use [apache-axis]
> instead; see: [What direction to go with the [axis] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276302/)

yet, [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis) and [apache-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis) are synonyms. How is either tag supposed to be used?

The linked meta post in the tag wiki shows that the community discussed this topic a while ago but haven't done anything about it.

Comment: I guess rene's proposal wasn't implemented.

Answer (score 10):

I'll copy-paste [rene's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379998/19123103) here since I agree with it:

> After some consultation in [The trogdor
> chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45301970#45301970)
> I propose the following:
>
> - break the synonym between [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis) and [apache-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis)
> - reinstate the original wiki for Axis.
> - retag [60 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baxis%5D+is%3Aq+%5Bapache%5D&mixed=0)
>   to [apache-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis)
> - revisit [15 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/978977)
>   that once had the tag [apache-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis)
> - let the community clean-up/retag [250 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baxis%5D+%22apache%22+is%3Aq&mixed=0)
>   that seems to be about apache axis.
> - let the community clean-up [axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis) for question about coordinates and optical axis.
>
> For sake of consistency I wonder if tag [axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/axis2) needs to be
> renamed to tag [apache-axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-axis2)

Comment: I have removed the synonym. I'll probably synonym [tag:axis2] after we get the Apache stuff retagged